# In java, how to convert a List<Long> to List<Number>?

Tags: java

I need to convert a list of Long to List of Number. How can I do that?

I have tried this:

```
        List<Number> numberList = longList.stream()
            .map(Long::new) // Convert each Long to a Long (not Number)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is this the best way?
Will there be loss of data?

Comment: `List<Number> numberList = new ArrayList<>(longList);` should be sufficient.  There is no point in converting a Long to a Long.  A Long is already a Number.

Comment: alternative: `List<Number> numberList = List.copyOf(longList);` - returns an [unmodifiable List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) and does **not** accept `null` elements

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert your `Long` objects. Every `Long` object is also a `Number` object, with [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html) being a subclass of [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/Number.html).

Make a new array of the supertype built from elements of a collection of the subtype.

```java
List < Long > longs = new ArrayList<>( List.of( 7L , 42L ) ) ;
List < Number > numbers = new ArrayList<>( longs ) ;
```

Use [`List.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)) for an unmodifiable list without nulls.

```java
List < Long > longs = new ArrayList<>( List.of( 7L , 42L ) ) ;
List < Number > numbers = List.copyOf( longs ) ;
```

> Is this the best way?

Define “best”.

> Will there be loss of data?

No.